# Mocha doesn't fail on assert(false)

Tags: mocha.js, sails.js

When using mocha to test a model of a sails app, It doesn't seem to run tests inside a callback:

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe('Dataset', function() {
  describe('create', function() {
    it('should create a new dataset', function() {
      Dataset.create({
        'name': 'testDataSet',
        'description': 'This dataset exists for testing purposes only.',
        'visibility': 'private',
        'data': {
          "foo": {
            "barn": "door",
            "color": "green"
          }
        }
      }, function(err, dataset) {
        assert(false);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This test is called by a script that initializes sails for it.
when Running this test, it passes, even though it should fail.

```
$: mocha

 1 passing (875ms)
```

Also it never seems to run the callback containing assert(false). Placing assert false at any other location yields the exepcted results, also sails seems to be running properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is asynchronous, so you should use callback in your testing function:

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe('Dataset', function() {
  describe('create', function() {
    it('should create a new dataset', function(done) {
      Dataset.create({
        'name': 'testDataSet',
        'description': 'This dataset exists for testing purposes only.',
        'visibility': 'private',
        'data': {
          "foo": {
            "barn": "door",
            "color": "green"
          }
        }
      }, function(err, dataset) {
        if (err) throw err;
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Add `assert` call wherever you need.

There are a lot of examples [here](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).